# How to save file from GCP VM on local directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, gcloud

I just got a Google Cloud Platform Deep Learning VM running and opened JupyterLab on my localhost. Now I can use the VM and my directory is `/home/jupyter`. I am running a program that exports results to csv's. I can save them on the VM in a separate folder, and then right-click and download them (not on the folder, but on the files). However, I'll have 10'000 files (at 2kb), how can I export those files either directly to a local directory (preferred, I use Mac), or a GCP Storage Bucket, or my Google Drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand taht you are using a Compute Engine isntance. In that case if your are not using a Windows bsaed machine you can run the [`gcloud compute scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) command.

In your case to copy an entire folder recursively you can use:

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse example-instance:~/narnia ~/wardrobe
```

To copy a folder called "narnia" in your Compute Engine instance to a folder named wardrobe in your local machine

Comment: I first had to give read/write permission for my local folder ```chmod 777 <folder-name>```, but then it worked. I used ```gcloud compute scp --project <name of project> --zone <name of zone> --recurse example-instance:/home/jupyter/results /Users/name/wardrobe```